Reus est judicandus
Is this grammatically correct?
What does it mean?
How else might it be said?
Please may you help with this
I believe I have described the question I am asking but it won't tell me why I don't meet standards

It is correct and means "The accused must be condemned." (Or perhaps more generally, "… must be judged," though I think judicare with a personal object strongly suggests condemnation.)
Alternative expressions would be … est damnandus, condemnandus, possibly also multandus (particularly with an ablative of the punishment, e.g. poena, exsilio, morte).

"Does it work in: Reus judicandus, intra vires, audi alteram partem" – no, that does not really make any sense and certainly does not explain "why a situation is unjust." You can of course ask all kinds of yes-no questions here, but if you have a particular thought you want to express in Latin, it would be easier for us if you just stated it in English.

Guilty to be judged, within power, with the other part.

Assuming these are grammatically accurate by themselves, what different mood do they give?
Reus judicandus or Reus ad judicandum or Reus judicandus est.
